# web flow don't recognize domainClass.list()

Tags: spring-webflow, grails-webflow

When calling this function in a webflow step:

```
domainClass.findAllByIdInList(givenList)
```

I get a null pointer exception. When executing:
    domainClass.list()

I get nothing. I tried to pass this code to the server and get the same exception. Why is this happening?

Comment: You need to provide more information. But if I had to take a guess... only classes annotated with 'Service', 'Component', etc... can be called from inside a flow.xml file. So make sure the 'domainClass' (that is a bad name btw) is annotated as  Service and is a scanned/registered by spring during startup.

Comment: start{on('next'){....
}.to "connectusers"
        }
        connectusers {
            on("next").to "congrats"
        }
        congrats()

Comment: You will probably need to provide more context. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve